# Mac's storage manager shows higher usage space for iCloud Drive than it actually is

Tags: icloud, imac, storage

Why does my MacBook storage manager (Apple icon > About This Mac > Storage tab) shows ~100 GB usage by iCloud Drive while running `du -sh` from iCloud's directory results only 18 GB? I have also checked the sizes of folders and files in iCloud Drive and was sure that in total they should be well below 100 GB. I have a iMac in my office that is connected to the same iCloud Drive as my MacBook, could it be that this has to do with it? But iCloud drive is supposed to store my files in Apple's cloud and why would my remote iMac have an overlapping storage with my MacBook through iCloud?

Comment: Do you have any files in the bin/trash?

Comment: I have emptied the trash, does not change that 100 GB too much.